# How can i show this message in mvc by using popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I show this message in a pop-up? I am trying to show this message in pop up in MVC.

```
string m = "Customer Deleted Successfully.";
return Json(new { Result = "Success", message = m },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to get server side responses in ajax..

```
   $.ajax({
    ...
    ...
    success:function(data)
     {
       if(data.Result == 'Success')
       {
        alert(data.message);
       }
     }
    })
```

In place of alert you can use [Bootstrap modal](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) or [Jquery Dialoag](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)  or [Toast notification](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/)  ..

Comment: Without Jquery is any option.

Comment: Bro @Ravi if you don't want to use JQuery then why do you returning `Json result`??